# How to set up a Lambda UDF for Redshift

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to build a simple Lambda UDF that when called, will just reverse the string. For example, with the following SQL statement `SELECT id, udf(string_col) from foo.table`, I'd like it to return something like:

```
id | string_col
_______________
 1 | sdrawkcab
 2 | hciwdnas
```

I can't figure how I should set the function up as the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-lambda-sql-udf.html) defines the structure of the input and output formats but I'm not really sure what type to define them as. I'm using the Lambda.EmptyFunction template as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a Redshift Scalar UDF, which is simpler than calling out to an AWS Lambda function.

It would be something like this:

```py
create function backwards (str text)
  returns text
stable
as $$
  return str[::-1]
$$ language plpythonu;
```

You can then use it like this: `SELECT backwards('foo')`

(I didn't test it, so let us know if it worked for you.)